# How to test for negative number and raise ValueError?

Tags: python

I'm working through this [tutorial](http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2015/05/13/python-oop-tdd-example-part1/#.VxEEfjE2sdQ). I'm working through this iteratively. At this point I have the following Binary class:

```
class Binary:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = str(value)
        if self.value[:2] == '0b':
            print('a binary!')
            self.value= int(self.value, base=2)
        elif self.value[:2] == '0x':
            print('a hex!')
            self.value= int(self.value, base=16)
        else:
            print(self.value)

    def __int__(self):
        if self.value[:1] == '-':
            return ValueError
        return int(self.value)
```

I'm running through a suite of tests using pytest, including:

```
 def __int__(self):
>       if self.value[:1] == '-':
E       TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I understand the error since I saved the parameter as an int. What is a good strategy to test for a negative number and raise a valueerror exception in this case?

Comment: `if self.value < 0`?

Comment: Two `__init__` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `value` is an int, then `value < 0` is the test that value is negative.  You should already know this.  Perhaps you should review the tutorial in the doc set.

A separate problem is that your **init** method is confused.  It turns the input into a string and sometimes turns the string (back?) into an int.  By the time **init** is finished, self.value should have an allowed value of the desired type.

Comment: Thanks Terry, I should have realized value < 0. On the second point I'm am turning all input parameters into a string because I can slice a string to look for things like  '0b'. but i was planning to store the value as an int. Can you suggest a better approach?